# CMake v3.4.1 finds CUDA 7.5 instead of CUDA 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cmake, cuda, gpu, xgboost

I am trying to install the GPU support for XGBoost but I get the following error when I try to build it with CMake:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "7.5", but required is at
least "8.0" (found /usr)
```

I only installed CUDA 8.0 and the environmental variables in .bashrc are specified as:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

How can I have CMake detect the right CUDA version?

Answer (score 3):

`PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` have no effect on cmake, so what you have tried will not work.

If you look at the documentation for [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) it is possible to provide a `PATHS` argument to tell cmake to look in non-standard locations

Unfortunately, if you look at the source for XGBoost's CMakeLists.txt, you can see it calls [`find_package(CUDA ...)`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L101), but doesn't allow the user to provide a `PATHS` option

```
if(USE_CUDA)
  find_package(CUDA 8.0 REQUIRED)
  ...
endif()
```

As such you are left with 2 options:

- Edit XGBoost's CMakeLists.txt file, and add `PATHS /usr/local/cuda-8.0` to the `find_package` call
- Install `cuda-8.0` into a standard location (eg: use `/usr/local` as your `PREFIX`, not `/usr/local/cuda-8.0`)

Comment: Thx Steve, ill try out option 1 :)

Comment: @Nesvold have you fixed that? How to add that cmake file?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to install the R version with GPU support. The issue was that I was running the commands from their [install guide](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#r-package-installation):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
cd R-package
R CMD INSTALL .
```

and then running the commands for GPU support:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON
```

I was able to avoid the issue by running:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON
make install -j
```